# A tuple assignment in Go

Tags: go

From [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> A tuple assignment assigns the individual elements of a multi-valued operation to a list of variables. There are two forms. In the first, the right-hand operand is a single multi-valued expression such as a function call, a channel or map operation, or a type assertion. The number of operands on the left-hand side must match the number of values. For instance, if f is a function returning two values, `x, y = f()` assigns the first value to x and the second to y. In the second form, the number of operands on the left must equal the number of expressions on the right, each of which must be single-valued, and the nth expression on the right is assigned to the nth operand on the left: `one, two, three = '一', '二', '三'`
>
> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of index expressions and pointer indirections (including implicit pointer indirections in selectors) on the left and the expressions on the right are all evaluated in the usual order. Second, the assignments are carried out in the left-to-right order.

Using [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Is0DdM1roXe) code ( `i, n = i+2, n-1` inside for loop) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    p := &Prime{}
    p.Generate(1000000)
    fmt.Println(p.Last()) // 15485863
}

func (p *Prime) Generate(n uint) {
    p.Primes = make([]uint64, 1, n)
    p.Primes[0] = 2
next:
    for i := uint64(3); n > 1; i, n = i+2, n-1 {
        q := uint64(math.Sqrt(float64(i)))
        for _, v := range p.Primes[1:] {
            if v > q {
                break
            }
            if i%v == 0 {
                continue next
            }
        }
        p.Primes = append(p.Primes, i)
        // n--
    }
}

type Prime struct {
    Primes []uint64
}

func (p *Prime) Last() uint64 {
    return p.Primes[len(p.Primes)-1]
}
```

Output is:

```
1999993
```

This is **not** a correct result.

And this code:

```
func (p *Prime) Generate(n uint) {
    p.Primes = make([]uint64, 1, n)
    p.Primes[0] = 2
next:
    for i := uint64(3); n > 1; i += 2 {
        q := uint64(math.Sqrt(float64(i)))
        for _, v := range p.Primes[1:] {
            if v > q {
                break
            }
            if i%v == 0 {
                continue next
            }
        }
        p.Primes = append(p.Primes, i)
        n--
    }
}
```

The output is correct:

```
15485863
```

`go version go1.11.5 linux/amd64`

Am I missing something on tuple [Assignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) in Go?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it is not tuple assignment that gives wrong result.

There is a subtle difference between the two code, which causes the bug. In the playgound code, `i,n = i+2,n-1` makes `n = n-1` runs everytimes the loop is iterated, while the github code only runs `n = n-1` when `i` is a prime (it skips `n--` if `continue next` runs).